# Laravel 7.1 - URL::defaults() not working in high priority middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am using subdomain routing heavily within my project, as it's a multi-tenant application with each tenant having their own subdomain.

As a result, all of my routes are wrapped in:

```php
Route::domain('{tenant}.'.config('app.base_url'))->group(function () {
    // My routes here!
});
```

To use the `route()` helper within my code, I need to pass it all of the route parameters associated with it. Every single route has `tenant` associated with it, so I constantly found myself repeating code and writing `route('my-route-name', ['tenant' => $request->route('tenant')]);`

I've created a middleware with the following code in it:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use URL;

class SetTenantFromRequest
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        list($subdomain) = explode('.', $request->getHost(), 2);
        URL::defaults(['tenant' => $subdomain]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And placed it in the HTTP `Kernel.php` file like so:

```php
protected $middleware = [
    TrustProxies::class,
    CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ValidatePostSize::class,
    TrimStrings::class,
    ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    WebHeaders::class,
    SetLanguage::class,
    SetTenantFromRequest::class,
];

// Removed for brevity...
protected $middlewarePriority = [
    StartSession::class,
    ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    SetTenantFromRequest::class,
    Authenticate::class,
    ThrottleRequests::class,
    AuthenticateSession::class,
    SubstituteBindings::class,
    Authorize::class,
];
```

I had to add it to the `$middlewarePriority` array as it needs to run before the `Authenticate` middleware. Since `Authenticate` calls `return route('login');`, I need that URL parameter available beforehand.

Now with doing all of this, I still get the following error thrown from the `Authenticate` middleware: `Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: login].`

If I run `ddd(URL::getDefaultParameters());` within the `Authenticate` middleware, it prints an empty array. However if I run the same `ddd(...)` within the `SetTenantFromRequest` middleware, it shows the tenant in there as I expect it to be.

Does anyone have an idea on how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving this from the global middleware stack to the web middleware stack alleviates the issue.

This forces me to add the tenant parameter to the `route(...)` call within my `Authenticate` middleware, but it does allow me to forgo it everywhere else.

Comment: I would still appreciate anyone who is able to explain why this is. Moving it to the beginning of the web stack causes the code to work for all other route helper usages in the project, but moving it to the end of the global stack causes it to fail.

Clearly something occurs between the execution of these two stacks, but I'm not sure what.